# LDAP Queries via URL

Tags: excel, vba, url, ldap

I am trying to make LDAP queries via Visual Basic. I don't have administrator access to the Active Directory, but I am able to view all user objects. I don't know what restrictions if any there are on me searching the directory via LDAP:// queries.

In the Excel application I am building, I have a column for the input of user IDs. Once a user inputs a user ID, I would like the other columns to be auto-populated based on server side information associated with that user (email address for example)

Let's say c.Value is the User ID value that has been input to the spreadsheet:

```
strUser = "CN=" & c.Value & ",OU=User Accounts,OU=Area,OU=Users,OU=Accounts,DC=joe,DC=bloggs,DC=co,DC=uk/"

Set objUser = GetObject("LDAP://" & strUser)
```

The problem is this -- where OU=Area is known, the search is successful. However, I would like the query to check all area OUs for the UserID. As far as I can tell they are not held or mirrored in a central location. Is it possible to use Wildcards in such a query?

Does anyone have any other ideas or suggestions as to alternate ways to go about this?

Thank you,

Tom

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Before I answer your question, here are some basic background knowlege on Active Directory.

- User objects on Active Directory contains a number of attributes.
- CN is one of the attribute on the user object.  It's not always the same as your login user name.
- samAccountName is string the pre-Windows 2000 Login Name.  This is probably what you are looking for.
- objects are stored hierarchically.  User object can be put under OU or container

To execute a LDAP query, you need to use an ADO connection object.  You need to pass in a LDAP query string to the ADO connection object.  The LDAP query string contains four parts.

- Root path, where we start the search.
- LDAP filter
- Returned attributes
- Search scope

The LDAP query string that you should use should be something like

```
<LDAP://OU=Users,OU=Accounts,DC=joe,DC=bloggs,DC=co,DC=uk>;(&(objectClass=user)(samAccountName=yourusername));adspath;subtree
```

- The root path in the above example is `<LDAP://OU=Users,OU=Accounts,DC=joe,DC=bloggs,DC=co,DC=uk>`.  It means start searching at this level
- Since you are searching for user, the LDAP filter is `(&(objectClass=user)(samAccountName=yourusername))`.  Of course, you need to replace `yourusername` to something else inside your code.  If you really want to do the search on CN, change it to CN here
- Returned attributes is a special attribute `adspath`, which allows you to bind to that object later
- I am assuming you are trying to search for all user objects under the same domain.  So, your search scope should be `subtree`

Here is a complete sample that I guess it should do your job

```
userName = "harvey"
ldapStr = "<LDAP://OU=Users,OU=Accounts,DC=joe,DC=bloggs,DC=co,DC=uk>;(&(objectClass=user)(samAccountName=" & userName & "));adspath;subtree

Set conn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
conn.Provider = "ADSDSOObject"
conn.Open "ADs Provider"
Set rs = conn.Execute(ldapStr)

While Not rs.EOF
   wscript.echo rs.Fields(0)
   rs.MoveNext
Wend
```

Comment: Thank you very much, you set me on the right track. Anyone looking to do the same I'd also recommend checking out the code here: http://www.rlmueller.net/ADOSearchTips.htm -- and check here for a list of common user object attributes: http://www.kouti.com/tables/userattributes.htm

Answer (score 0):

You are probably see anonymous style access rights.  Thus you can read some default attributes.  What you want to do is make sure you are authenticated as a user with sufficient rights to read the data you are interested in.

If the UserID is really the users Pre-Windows 2000 Login Name (aka sAMAccountName) then search for the full DN of the user whose sAMAccountName=c.Value.

By the way, odds are very good that the CN= is not the short name, but is rather some version of the persons First and Last name, which is the ADUC MMC default pattern.